# How to get N numbers of data points which are nearest from a cluster's center?

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, k-means

I want to get N nearest data points from center (based on Euclidean Distance) in each cluster after deploying K-means algorithm. I am able to get the indices of data points using

```
np.where(km.labels_ == 0)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `transform` method of the `kmeans` class which calculates the distance of each data point to each of the cluster.

Then assuming you want the top `N` points from the 0th index `cluster` then you can just do:

```
cluster = 0
N = 2
np.sort(kmeans.transform(X)[:,cluster])[:N]
```

Comment: Is there any way to get the features of the nearest data points when their distance from center of the cluster is known?

Comment: Lets say I have 3 features namely, height, weight and color and I want to get these features of data points nearest from a cluster's center.

Comment: I'd suggest to edit the question or even better make a new one with an explanation of what you want to achieve with expected output.

Answer (score 0):

A simple four step process:

1. Compute the mean
2. Compute the distances from the mean
3. Select the k smallest with `argmin`
4. map back the sunset indexes to dataset indexes by indexing into the return value of `np.where`